# Exporting .xlsx file using Apache POI not working

Tags: java, grails, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm reading xlsx file. Below is my code snippet which works fine in my local machine however which doesn't work in server when deployed. While reading the workbook it gives a problem! there are no errors logged. I'm not able to figure out the problem.

I'm using Grails and Apache POI 3.11

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

```
def uploadFile() {
    try{
        def file = request.getFile('file')          
        def xWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream())
        String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename())
        if(fileExtension.equals("xlsx"))
            exportXlsxFile(xWorkbook)
    }catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception in uploadFile(): ${e.message}")
    }

}

def exportXlsxFile(def xWorkbook){
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public")
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="
        + "Sales.xlsx")
    def outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
    xWorkbook.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
}
```

Grails BuildConfig.groovy's poi dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11"
}
```

Comment: When you are saying "doesn't work in server when deployed", which part doesn't work. Are you able to get the MultiPartFile? Or the export does not work?

Comment: I'm able to get the multi part file, export is not working!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you `render xWorkbook`, instead of using `response.getOutputStream()`. It sounds obvious but are you sure `if(fileExtension.equals("xlsx"))` returns true?. I suggest to use `equalsIgnoreCase`, instead of `equals`.

Comment: how about using response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
                response.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel');
                response.setHeader ("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=docs.xlsx"); and removing the outputStream.close()

Comment: I tried this but no luck, thanks for the help. I strongly feel that this problem is due to some missing jars! so far I have added: poi-3.11.jar, 
poi-ooxml-3.11.jar, 
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar, 
dom4j-1.6.1.jar, 
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, 
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar, 
stax-api-1.0.1.jar, 
commons-codec-1.9.jar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apache POI [has a detailed and comprehensive page on dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), I'd suggest you review that. And possibly consider upgrading to the most recent version too - [lots of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.11)

Comment: This got worked after I made use of grails excel plugin in BuildConfig.groovy file
compile "org.grails.plugins:excel-import:1.0.0"
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"  //dependency for excel plugin